# Translation Exercise Unit 1 - Part 1 [Basic Spoken Chinese Practice Essentials]

Tags: translation

I am trying to learn mandarin and I am using the Basic Spoken Chinese Practice Essentials Workbook. Unfortunately there is no answer key to that book. Would be great if someone could check if I translated correctly.

1. Where is Ke Leien going?

   - Kē Léi'ēn dào nǎr qù?
   - Kē Léi'ēn dào nǎr qù a?
2. I'm going to the cafeteria. How about you?

   - Wǒ qù shítáng. Nǐ ne?
   - Wǒ dào shítáng qù. Nǐ ne?
3. Wang Jingsheng is going back to the dorm.

   - Wáng Jīngshēng huí sùshè.
4. Ke Leien is going to take care of some things.

   - Kē Léi'ēn qù bàn yìdiǎnr shìr.
5. You're going to the library; I also am going to the library.

   - Nǐ qù túshūguǎn. Wǒ yě qù.
   - Nǐ dào túshūguǎn qù. Wǒ yě qù.

Comment: I think your translations are quite right. Although some of your Chinese sentences might not indicate the English's tense, it should not be a problem if you put those sentences into the proper contexts. The tense in Chinese is often implicit anyways.

Comment: @dan Thanks for your comment. Tenses are not yet introduced in the grammar, just example sentences and vocabulary.

Answer (score 1):

Your translations are basically correct, the only improvement I can talk about is to show the present continuous tense

> Where is Ke Leien going?

Can be translated to

> Kē Léi'ēn **yao** qu na?

And the second one

> I'm going to the cafeteria. How about you?

Can be translated to

> Wǒ **yao** qù shítáng. Nǐ ne?

And the third one

> Wang Jingsheng is going back to the dorm.

Can be translated to

> Wáng Jīngshēng **yao** huí sùshè.

And the fourth one

> Ke Leien is going to take care of some things.

Can be translated to

> Kē Léi'ēn **yao** qù bàn yìdiǎnr shìr.

Lastly

> You're going to the library, I also am going to the library.

Can be translated to

> Nǐ **yao** qù túshūguǎn. Wǒ yě **yao** qù.

By the way, how did you type pinyin with tune on it?